# How do I select just few columns with ORMLite and c#?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I have a query involving several tables, and I need to select only few columns of the result.

I've looked everywhere with no luck, the few things I tried did not work.

Can someone point me to the right direction? The documentation is pretty smoky too...

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class which groups columns (properties) of several tables you need to select.

Then call OrmLite like this:

```
var q = db.From<Customer>()
      .Join<CustomerAddress>();

var customers = db.Select<FullCustomerInfo,Customer>(q); // where FullCustomerInfo is the class which groups required properties
```

[Source for more explanation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#select-data-from-multiple-tables-into-a-custom-poco)